# Permutable subgroups, but a conjugate one one group does not commute with other group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A,B \le G$ subgroups. Do you know an example where $AB = BA$, but $A^gB \ne BA^g$ for some conjugate $A^g$ of $A$?

Comment: Hint: there is an example in $S_3$ with $A = B$.

Comment: Okay, yes that is simple; but if $A \ne B$? Any example in this case?

Comment: Probably you can do the same thing in $S_4$ with $A$ and $B$ still both of order $2$.

Comment: Okay, yes I see!

Comment: I suggest you add an answer yourself, possibly generalizing the examples.

Comment: To make the problem yet a bit more challenging: Can you find an example of a group $G$ with subgroups $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=BA$ but $A^g B\neq BA^g$ for some $g$ **where $g$ lies in $B$**?